# In kernel-space C, do I need to deallocate string memory before giving it a new value?

Tags: c, arrays, linux, string, kernel

The below is just a snippet of code. I don't know if it will compile, but it should be the gist of my problem.

```
char **argv = NULL;
int argc = 0;
char *str = "Hello World";

argv = argv_split(GFP_KERNEL, str, &argc);
```

At this point, I would expect that:

`argv[0]` returns "Hello".

`argv[1]` returns "World".

But now I would want to say "Hello StackOverflow".

So I try something like:

```
argv[1] = kstrdup("StackOverflow", GFP_KERNEL);
```

And in my code, `argv` would return "Hello StackOverflow".

But I believe that the "World" is still allocated in memory somewhere, and I don't know how to free it. I tried things like:

```
kfree(argv[1]);
argv[1] = kstrdup("StackOverflow", GFP_KERNEL);
```

but it ends up giving me seg faults. I even tried passing in the dereference as kfree(&argv[argc - 1]) but it still gives the same issue. I noticed that in the code for [argv_split](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/lib/argv_split.c?v=2.6.24), kzalloc is used, so I tried kzfree and that didn't work. But I also noticed that it's allocating the memory for the entire array and zeroing it. `argv_split` returns an array of pointers to strings.

So my question is: Do I need to free the argv[1] before giving it "StackOverflow"? If so, how would I go about for doing that? It doesn't seem that I can deallocate that memory on an element-by-element basis.

Comment: You correctly call `kfree(argv[1]);` before assigning new value to `argv[1]`. It seems that reason for segfaults is somewhere else in your code.